# Convert JSON object to individual columns in spark java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark Dataset and want to convert it into individual columns.

Using Spark 2.2 and java 1.8

```
DF.printSchema()
root
 |-- ute.internal.id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- ute.features.serialized: string (nullable = false)

DF.show()

{"ute.id":"123","ute.isBoolean":"true","ute.sortPriority":"5"},
{"ute.id":"456","ute.isBoolean":"false","ute.sortPriority":"6"}

Expected output - 
===============
ute.id|ute.feature.isBoolean|ute.sortPriority
123   |true                 |5 
456   |false                |6
```

Someone can help on this?.Thanks.

Comment: The schema you have provided does not match with the output of `show`. The other column `ute.features.serialized` is not visible. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
val newDf = sqlContext.read.json(df.rdd)
```

It will give you a dataframe with all json columns

Example

```
  val json2 ="""{"ute.id":"123","ute.isBoolean":"true","ute.sortPriority":"5"},
              |{"ute.id":"456","ute.isBoolean":"false","ute.sortPriority":"6"}"""
  val jsonRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(json2))
  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)


  val df = sqlContext.read.json(jsonRdd)
  df.show(false)

+------+-------------+----------------+
|ute.id|ute.isBoolean|ute.sortPriority|
+------+-------------+----------------+
|123   |true         |5               |
+------+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: ute.features.serialized is one of dataframe column.So i think we cannot use read.json method.